# Problems getting data from AJAX to PHP (and back)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The idea is that this script POSTs the value of the text input in my html form to `emailform.php`, which takes that data and adds it to a `.txt` file. I think what I'm having trouble with is setting the value of `$email` in the PHP to that of the html text input. As a result, currently when the script is triggered I get two alerts (first 'error' then 'complete', from the .fail and .complete functions) and then the page reloads. That's why I think the problem is with the information being returned from the PHP but maybe I'm wrong.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="emailSubmitSidebar" placeholder=" Your Email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="submitButton" id="subscribeButton">
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var subscribeButton = $('#subscribeButton');
        subscribeButton.click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'emailform.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {email: $("input[name=email]").val()},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert("Added!");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                alert("complete");
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

And below is the PHP, I've added the first two lines to check for any errors, of which there are none anymore. What's strange is that when I run the PHP separately, the `echo` line prints the number 3 on the page without any apparent cause. I commented out the variable `$email` because I was led to believe it was better/necessary to first check if it `isset`.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $fileHandle = fopen('emailList.txt', 'a') OR die ("Can't open file\n");
    $email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
    // $email=$_POST['email'];
    $result = fwrite ($fileHandle, "$email; \n");
    fclose($fileHandle);
    echo (!$result) ? "error" : $result;
    die;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your data, try to serialize it into a json data array:

```
var data = $(form).serialize();

$.ajax({
  url: 'emailform.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'text',
  data: data,
})
```

The values will be sent as a normal post request, so the email address will be in `$_POST['email']`;

**Updated from here**

The jquery .done() and .fail() functions require http status codes to work, so your php file should return these codes. When a request is made and succeeded anything in the 200 range will be ok. While on an error, something from the 400 or 500 range should be returned. There is a full list here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

So the ajax .success function is fired when 2xx is returned (replace .done with .success) and the .error is called when status code 4xx or 5xx is returned. See php below how to implement this.

The number 3 you are getting is the $return value of the fwrite function, according to: https://www.php.net/fwrite

> fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error.

Make your php like this:

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

if($fileHandle = fopen('emailList.txt', 'a')) {

  if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $result = fwrite ($fileHandle, "$email; \n");
    fclose($fileHandle);
  
    if(isset($result) && !empty($result)) { // Something was written
      http_response_code(200);
      echo "File written";
    } else { // Writing failed
      http_response_code(500);
      echo "Writing of file failed";
    }
  } else { // Empty email
    http_response_code(500);
    echo "Email was empty";
  }
} else { // File could not be opened
  http_response_code(500);
  echo "File could not be opened for writing";
}
?>
```

Comment: This runs without error but the email does not get written to the text file and the page reloads after clicking (and the input shows up in the URL as a parameter). What do I do @Neograph734?

Comment: Please update your question with the things you have in place now. I see you updated it, but the wrong `data: ('input').val()` is still there. Then we can have another look at it. The reloading makes no sense... Also remove the `OR DIE`, throw an error with the correct http_response_code instead. And you might want to use `fwrite ($fileHandle, "$email; \n");` .txt files don't understand <br/> ;)

Comment: I've updated the question! Thanks for your help so far :). I've changed the `data:`. I'm not sure how to replace `OR DIE` with what you suggest. And yeah I caught the <br/> issue. See the new description in the question. Basically the PHP script echoes the number 3 and I think that is triggering the alerts. @Neograph734

Comment: Updated the answer. Removed `OR DIE`, the number 3 and implemented http response codes.

Answer (score 0):

(Simple)

Change HTML to:

```
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="emailSubmitSidebar" placeholder=" Your Email">
```

Change JS to :

```
     $.ajax({
         url: 'emailform.php',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'text',
         data: {email: $("input[name=email]").val()}
     })
    .done(function(data) {
         // there checking 
         alert("success!")
     })
```

Change PHP to:

```
  $fileHandle = fopen('emailList.txt', 'a') OR die ("Can't open file\n");
  $email=$_POST["email"];
  $result = fwrite ($fileHandle, "$email; <br/>");
  fclose($fileHandle);
  echo (!$result)? "error" : $result;
  die;
```

Comment: I get an alert with 'error'. It's set off by the .fail (I checked). I think the problem lies with the $email variable in php since the text file is receiving the line breaks but not the email. @voodoo417

Comment: @user3163188  check `var_dump($email)` before fwrite.

Comment: @user3163188 Or try to change   in `$.ajax`  to  `data: {email: $("input[name=email]").val()}`

Comment: @user3163188 and add to `<input type="text" name="email"` this `value=""`

Comment: I did everything and no longer get an error but the page reloads and the email doesn't get written to the text file (it does get added as a parameter to the URL). Any ideas? @voodoo417

Comment: Wait actually it does work, the email is getting written. But I'm getting an error and the page reloads. So something is still off @voodoo417

Comment: I removed the data string inside .done(function(data)) which made it work but still with error and reload.